# Confused about this php code

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach($items as $value)
{
   if($value['item1']=='somestring')
   { 
       // some PHP code...
   }
}
```

Shouldn't `$value` refer to each value in `$items` array. What do they mean by `$value['item1']`? Does it mean `$items` is a multidimensional array or something?

Comment: That certainly looks like a correct assumption.

Comment: First thing in PHP world is to learn `echo`, second should be `var_dump` ;)

Comment: `echo '<pre>',print_r($items),'</pre>';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means $value is an array and therefore $items is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

The `$foo[]` syntax is used by [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [objects that emulate them](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) (if that's what you mean). The index can be an integer or a string. As you already point out, PHP allows multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you print $key and $value then out show you good result

```
foreach($items as $key=>$value) // $items contain array mean multidimensional
    {
        print_r($value);
        print($key);//$key is index value

        //item1 is array element and $value is array exist in $items
        if($value['item1']=='somestring') 
           { 
             some PHP code...
          }
    }
```

so $items  multidimensional array and $value array exist in $items array that's by $items  multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

It means that `$items` is a multi-dimensional array.

And its looped over.

It has following structure for example:

```
array(
0 => array('item1' => 'something'),
1 => array('item1' => 'something1')
);
```

Through this code, we are looping so, in the statement,

```
foreach($items as $value)
```

We are getting the inner arrays `0`, `1`, .. and so on.

And in the line, `if($value['item1']=='somestring')`, we are getting array elements of `0`, `1`, and so on.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. `'item1'` is the key to one of the elements inside the array `$value`.
2. So yes, this makes `$items` a multidimensional array.
3. All above are true if no errors are found running the code.